# Compute L2 distance with numpy using matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to do it by myself the assignments from [Stanford CS231n 2017 CNN course](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/2017/).

I'm trying to compute L2 distance using only matrix multiplication and sum broadcasting with Numpy. L2 distance is:

[image]

And I think I can do it if I use this formula:

[image]

The following code shows three methods to compute L2 distance. If I compare the output from the method `compute_distances_two_loops` with the output from method `compute_distances_one_loop`, both are equals. But I compare the output from the method `compute_distances_two_loops` with the output from the method `compute_distances_no_loops`, where I have implemented the L2 distance using only matrix multiplication and sum broadcasting, they are different.

```
def compute_distances_two_loops(self, X):
    """
Compute the distance between each test point in X and each training point
in self.X_train using a nested loop over both the training data and the 
test data.

Inputs:
- X: A numpy array of shape (num_test, D) containing test data.

Returns:
- dists: A numpy array of shape (num_test, num_train) where dists[i, j]
  is the Euclidean distance between the ith test point and the jth training
  point.
"""
    num_test = X.shape[0]
    num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
    dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
    for i in xrange(num_test):
        for j in xrange(num_train):
            #####################################################################
            # TODO:                                                             #
            # Compute the l2 distance between the ith test point and the jth    #
            # training point, and store the result in dists[i, j]. You should   #
            # not use a loop over dimension.                                    #
            #####################################################################
            #dists[i, j] = np.sqrt(np.sum((X[i, :] - self.X_train[j, :]) ** 2))
            dists[i, j] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(X[i, :] - self.X_train[j, :])))
            #####################################################################
            #                       END OF YOUR CODE                            #
            #####################################################################
    return dists

def compute_distances_one_loop(self, X):
    """
Compute the distance between each test point in X and each training point
in self.X_train using a single loop over the test data.

Input / Output: Same as compute_distances_two_loops
"""
    num_test = X.shape[0]
    num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
    dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
    for i in xrange(num_test):
        #######################################################################
        # TODO:                                                               #
        # Compute the l2 distance between the ith test point and all training #
        # points, and store the result in dists[i, :].                        #
        #######################################################################
        dists[i, :] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(self.X_train - X[i, :]), axis = 1))
        #######################################################################
        #                         END OF YOUR CODE                            #
        #######################################################################
    print(dists.shape)
    return dists

def compute_distances_no_loops(self, X):
    """
Compute the distance between each test point in X and each training point
in self.X_train using no explicit loops.

Input / Output: Same as compute_distances_two_loops
"""
    num_test = X.shape[0]
    num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
    dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
    #########################################################################
    # TODO:                                                                 #
    # Compute the l2 distance between all test points and all training      #
    # points without using any explicit loops, and store the result in      #
    # dists.                                                                #
    #                                                                       #
    # You should implement this function using only basic array operations; #
    # in particular you should not use functions from scipy.                #
    #                                                                       #
    # HINT: Try to formulate the l2 distance using matrix multiplication    #
    #       and two broadcast sums.                                         #
    #########################################################################
    dists = np.sqrt(-2 * np.dot(X, self.X_train.T) +
                    np.sum(np.square(self.X_train), axis=1) +
                    np.sum(np.square(X), axis=1)[:, np.newaxis])
    print(dists.shape)
    #########################################################################
    #                         END OF YOUR CODE                              #
    #########################################################################
    return dists
```

You can find a full working testable code [here](https://pastebin.com/a0aT0Y6T).

Do you know what am I doing wrong in `compute_distances_no_loops`, or wherever?

**UPDATE:**

The code that throws the error message is:

```
dists_two = classifier.compute_distances_no_loops(X_test)

# check that the distance matrix agrees with the one we computed before:
difference = np.linalg.norm(dists - dists_two, ord='fro')
print('Difference was: %f' % (difference, ))
if difference < 0.001:
    print('Good! The distance matrices are the same')
else:
    print('Uh-oh! The distance matrices are different')
```

And the error message:

```
Difference was: 372100.327569
Uh-oh! The distance matrices are different
```

Comment: Can you double check the dot multiplication notation there, I think its supposed to be like `X.dot(self.X_train.T)` ? Could it be that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, when I tried `np.allclose(compute_distances_no_loops(Y, Z), compute_distances_one_loop(Y, Z))`, it returns `True`

Comment: I get the error after running the method `compute_distances_no_loops`.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I have updated the question with the code that throws the error and the error message.

Comment: I think you have to use broadcast multiplication, not a dot product

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is how you can compute pairwise distances between rows of X and Y without creating any 3-dimensional matrices:

```
def dist(X, Y):
    sx = np.sum(X**2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    sy = np.sum(Y**2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return np.sqrt(-2 * X.dot(Y.T) + sx + sy.T)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Your code works like a charm. But, I don't know why, I'm still getting the same message: "Difference was: 372100.327569 - Uh-oh! The distance matrices are different".

Comment: Something that helped me understand the "magic" of numpy that is happening in the operation sx + sy.T:
```python
sx = np.sum(X**2, axis=1, keepdims=True);
print("sx.shape", sx.shape);
# sx.shape (500, 1);

sy = np.sum(Y**2, axis=1, keepdims=True);
print("sy.T.shape", sy.T.shape);
# sy.T.shape (1, 5000);

square_sums = sx + sy.T;
print("square_sums.shape", square_sums.shape);
# square_sums.shape (500, 5000);
```

Comment: Note that this works because if you distribute `(X-Y)^2` = `(X-Y)*(X-Y)` you get `X^2 + Y^2 - 2XY`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for the pairwise distance.

There is an amazing trick to do that in a single line. You have to cleverly play with the broadcasting:

```py
X_train = np.expand_dims(self.X_train, 1) # shape: [num_train, 1, D]
X_test = np.expand_dims(X, 0) # shape: [1, num_tests, D]
dists = np.square(X_train - X_test) # Thanks to broadcast [num_train, num_tests, D]
dists = np.sqrt(np.sum(dists, axis=-1)) # [num_train, num_tests]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tested it, and line  `dists = np.square(X_train - X_test)  # Thanks to broadcast [num_train, num_tests, D]` throws the error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 7.15 GiB for an array with shape (5000, 500, 3072) and data type uint8`.

Comment: This is cause you have a lot of data loaded in memory. But you will have se problem with other approaches trying to do this pairwise distance.

Comment: This code is part from an assignment from an university and I don't think they, the professors, make it to not been able to execute it unless you have a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue comes from inconsistent array shapes.

```python
#a^2 matrix (500, 1) 
alpha = np.sum(np.square(X), axis=1)
alpha = alpha.reshape(len(alpha), 1)
print(alpha.shape)
#b^2 matrix (1, 5000) 
beta  = np.sum(np.square(self.X_train.T), axis=0)
beta = beta.reshape(1, len(beta))
print(beta.shape)
#ab matrix (500, 5000)
alphabeta = np.dot(X, self.X_train.T)
print(alphabeta.shape)

dists = np.sqrt(-2 * alphabeta + alpha + beta)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a late response, but I've solved it in a different way and wanted to post it. When I was solving this, I was unaware of the numpy's column-row vector subtractions from the matrix. As it turns out, we can subtract nx1 or 1xm vector from nxm and when we do it, subtracts from every row-column vector. If one works with a library that doesn't support this kind of behavior, he/she can use mine. For this situation, I've worked it out the math, and the result is the following one:

```
sum_x_train=np.sum(self.X_train**2,axis=1, keepdims=True)
sum_x_test=np.sum(X**2,axis=1, keepdims=True)
sum_2x_tr_te=np.dot(self.X_train,X.T)*2
sum_x_train=np.dot(sum_x_train,np.ones((1,X.shape[0])))
sum_x_test=np.dot(sum_x_test,np.ones((1,self.X_train.shape[0])))
dists=np.sqrt(sum_x_test.T+sum_x_train-sum_2x_tr_te).T
```

The downside of this approach is it uses more memory.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for function `compute_distances_no_loops()` that the OP asked for. I don't use the `sqrt()` function for performance reason:

```py
def compute_distances_no_loops(self, X):
    num_test = X.shape[0]
    num_train = self.X_train.shape[0]
    dists = np.zeros((num_test, num_train))
    #---------------
    # Get square of X and X_train
    X_sq = np.sum(X**2, axis=1, keepdims=True) 
    Xtrain_sq = np.sum(self.X_train**2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    # Calculate (squared) dists as (X_train - X)**2 = X_train**2 - 2*X_train*X + X**2
    dists = -2*X.dot(self.X_train.T) + X_sq + Xtrain_sq.T
    #---------------  
    return dists
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thank you @Community! I edited my comment. Hope it is clearer now.