# Calculating euclidean distance using PyTorch with no loops (only using vectorization)

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, linear-algebra

I am currently trying to work through the MIT Deep Learning and Computer Vision course (EECS 498-007 / 598-005) Assignment 1 by myself, which seems to have a rough equivalent in Stanford CS 231n.

**Problem-formulation:**
Create a function, which computes the pairwise euclidean distance **inputs:** xtrain,xtest. Dimensions: [N,x,x] and [M,x,x] (with x being the same number)

**output:** distance-matrix of shape [N,M] expressing the distance between each training point and each testing point.

There is given a **hint** in the assignment:
Try to formulate the Euclidean distance using two broadcast sums     and a matrix multiply.

[I am trying to implement this mathematical operation using broadcasting, where the middle term is a simple matrix-multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf8Gj.png)

I am struggling with the tensor-shapes. My implementation so far is as follows:

```
def euc_no_loop(x,y):
  #hint: two broadcast sums
  xsq = torch.sum(x**2,axis=1)
  print(xsq.shape)
  ysq = torch.sum(y**2,axis=1)
  print(ysq.shape)
  #and one matrix multiply
  mixprod = -2 * x.view(x.shape[0],-1).matmul(y.view(y.shape[0],-1).T)
  print(mixprod.shape)
  euc_dist = torch.sqrt(xsq + mixprod + ysq.unsqueeze(1).T)
  return euc_dist
```

With inputs being:

x = torch.randn(5,3,3)

y = torch.randn(3,3,3)

shapes become:

xsq: [5,3]

ysq: [3,3]

mixprod: [5,3]

And output dimension becomes [3,5,3].

Many other StackOverflow threads exist, where numpy is used - but the numpy dot-product seems to be more flexible than torch.matmul.

Example on numpy-solution: [Compute L2 distance with numpy using matrix multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952027/compute-l2-distance-with-numpy-using-matrix-multiplication)

I simply don't understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by euclidean distance as Euclidean distance is generally defined between two points in (Euclidean) space, whereas each element of `xtrain` and `xtest` are instead arrays of shape `[x,x]` in your example

Comment: It seems that you have too many dimensions in `xtrain` and `xtest`. And in fact the example in numpy that you linked has only two-dimensional rather than 3-dimensional inputs. Please verify the dimensions of your inputs

Comment: That is a good point. 

The point is, that the first dimension is number of images in each set, and thus they need not be same size. The other two dimensions are corresponding pixel values in a matrix-grid. Thus, the pairwise distance is to be calculated between corresponding pixel-values between each, and to be summed giving a total distance between training-image i and test-image j in euc_dist[i,j].

Answer (score 0):

Input tensors probably should have two dimensions in order to compute pairwise distance. So I assume that those x by x matrices should be summed altogether like (N, x, x) => (N)

```
def euc_no_loop(x, y):
  # Suppose x has (N, x, x) and Y has (M, x, x) dimensions
  xsq = torch.sum(x**2, dim=(1, 2))  # (N,)
  print(xsq.shape)
  ysq = torch.sum(y**2, dim=(1, 2))  # (M,)
  print(ysq.shape)

  mixprod = -2 * x.view(x.shape[0], -1) @ y.view(y.shape[0], -1).T  # (N, M)
  print(mixprod.shape)

  euc_dist = torch.sqrt(xsq.unsqueeze(1) + mixprod + ysq.unsqueeze(0))  # (N,1)+(N,M)+(1,M) => (N, M)
  return euc_dist
```

Or just flatten the input tensors

```
x = x.flatten(start_dim=1)
y = y.flatten(start_dim=1)
```

Comment: This seems to behave exactly as intended. So much simpler!
Thank you so much